# How to Redirect after Generating File in SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

My goal is to redirect the page after generating a file, but my code below does not generate file because it redirect to another page. How can i do generate file after redirect? is it possible to do this in Server-Side Scripting(Suitelet)?

Suitelet SuiteScript 2.0  :

```
response.writeFile({
              file:loanPortFolio
            });

//There are no redirect before, only generate file, but because i can't generate again , 
//I need to refresh the page to generate again. so i Add this line of code to redirect me to same page.

 response.sendRedirect({
          type: http.RedirectType.SUITELET,
          identifier : 'customscript_loan_port_detailed_report',
          id : 'customdeploy_loan_portf_detailed_report',
          parameters: {
                    type : 'monthly'
                  }
 });

//Result? I can't generate because it redirect to another page -_-
```

Comment: so, do you want to have the ability to download that file or save it in the file cabinet? Rendering and redirecting do not make sense. Elaborate in the steps you want to achieve this and it would be handy to help you.

Comment: The purpose of this script is to generate a monthly report and download it to computer so they can view after. I don't want for the user to go to File cabinet and download it, if i did this, the page that i created will be useless. actually downloading the file is working, but because user need to press the submit button to download the file, user will not be able to generate again without refreshing the page.

Comment: for the user to download a file again without refreshing the page, I Add redirect so it will redirect to the same page, but this idea failed because the redirecting will not wait for the file to download it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't have both : writefile and redirect : if one is executed, the other one will be "cancelled".

You didn't put the complete code, but I assume that you are using form within a suitelet, and you did add a submit button for your form and within the POST you are generating the file and using writeFile.

If that is the case, then one way to achieve your goal is, in post, after generating the file, instead of using writeFile, you can add an HTML field to your form and set its value to something like:

```
'<a href=[url] target=_blank>Download file</a>'
```

with: [url] is the link you can get from your file object (loanPortFolio).

With this, after submit, the user will see the link, and because target is '_blank', the file will be generated in a new tab/window and so the form window will remain opened and it can be used again.